# Searching through different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several tables with a `Sequence` as the primary key.

They are unrelated at all, there are no foreign keys or anything, or anything that could link one to another, so `join` won't work.

`Union` won't work either because they are basically different tables.

I know that you could assign "null" to those columns that exist in one table but not another, if that's the case, I could just make everything into one big table with `Sparse Columns', but I just "personally" don't like a table with too many null values.

The only relationship they got is that they share a Sequence as a primary key, so they all have a unique primary key, even across each other.

So, how can I "effectively" search through all these tables for the unique primary key I'm looking for instead of selecting through each table until a non-null result is returned?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `they are unrelated at all, there are no foreign keys or anything, so join won't work` `JOIN` does not depend on the primary or foreign key of the tables that involve in a `JOIN`. `they are basically different tables so union won't work either.` `UNION` will work if you are selecting same number of columns with matching data type. Please edit your question and include [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you want to achieve

Comment: What do you want to get as a result of this search? If there are different tables, what result set would you expect? Just which table sequence belongs to?

Comment: If they are all *completely* unrelated, then why do they use the same `SEQUENCE` object? That implies there *is* some kind of relationship between them, as otherwise rows from the different tables having the same PK/ID wouldn't matter.

Comment: Because, they are actually derived classes from an interface, it'll only make sense when they are "reconstructed back into the corresponding class".

Comment: So what is your expected result? If they have completely different columns how do you propose to show that in one query?

Comment: @Charlieface The result of that specific table. For example, if the result is in, say, `tableB`, then `SELECT * FROM tableB`.

Comment: Again I will ask you: if tableA has columns `ID, I, J` and tableB has columns `ID, X, Y` how do you want to show that? You can't have dynamic columns in one query. You are best off using separate `SELECT` statements

Comment: @Charlieface If ID of, say, 5, is in table (ID, X, Y), then shows that record (5, 3, 8), for example.

Comment: But what would the columns be called? Again you can't have dynamic columns in one query. We could do `Column1, Column2` but that sounds pretty silly

Comment: @Charlieface Nenad Zivkovic has solved my problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it suits you, something with dynamic query can look like this:

```
create table tableA ( id int, col1 char ,col2 char );
create table tableB ( id int, col3 int ,col4 int );
create table tableC ( id int, col5 bit ,col6 bit );

insert tableA values (1, 'a', 'b');
insert tableB values (2, 2, 2);
insert tableC values (3, 0, 1);
 
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

with cte_union AS 
(
    select id, 'tableA' as t from tableA
    union all
    select id, 'tableB' from tableB
    union all
    select id, 'tableC' from tableC
)
select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + t + ' WHERE id = ' + CAST(id AS nvarchar(MAX)) 
from cte_union 
where id = 1;   --your @id param

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to find which table has the ID?
Then you could `LEFT JOIN` each table to a query with the number.

```
SELECT q.id
, COUNT(a.id) AS A
, COUNT(b.id) AS B
, COUNT(c.id) AS C
, COUNT(d.id) AS D
, CASE 
  WHEN COUNT(a.id) > 0 THEN 'TableA'
  WHEN COUNT(b.id) > 0 THEN 'TableB'
  WHEN COUNT(c.id) > 0 THEN 'TableC'
  WHEN COUNT(d.id) > 0 THEN 'TableD'
  END AS Tbl
FROM (select 123 as id) q
LEFT JOIN tableA a ON a.id = q.id
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.id = q.id
LEFT JOIN tableC c ON c.id = q.id
LEFT JOIN tableD d ON d.id = q.id
GROUP BY q.id
```

Then select from the table that has the id.

F.e. the query above could return a result like :

```
id     A    B    C    D    Tbl
------ ---- ---- ---- ---- -------------
123    0    1    0    0    TableB
```

So TableB would have id = 123

Comment: No, I want the "full result". If the result is in, say, `tableB`, then I want `SELECT * FROM tableB`. But thanks anyway.

Comment: And that's the problem! I don't know "which table" has that ID.

Comment: I guess you're looking for a solution with Dynamic Sql.  Where the query depends on which table has the id.

Answer (score 0):

If by "effectively" you mean performance then loop through all tables and break when the result set isn't empty.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to "avoid", is it possible?

Comment: It is possible with `UNION` and dynamic sql but is not fast or elegant

Comment: Is that so!? So it's still the best to loop through each table until a non-null result is returned!?